# Multiple ViewPagers Inside Single ListView is Crashing

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

When Swipe through Viewpagers its Working Perfectly which i had done using **setId()** method for **ViewPagers** on **getView()** method of **BaseAdapter**.

Code Of Implementation is similar to this thread, which i found here:
[On This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920459/placing-viewpager-as-a-row-in-listview)

Just added setId(position+1) after creating each ViewPager's Object.

[image]

***But when i start scrolling through List (Horizontally) Application is getting crashed showing below Error in Logcat:***

> 06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find
>   resource ID #0x7 06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:1653)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   atandroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:440) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   com.example.democardswipelistview.CustomSwipeAdapter.getView(CustomSwipeAdapter.java:72)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2012) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:705) 06-18 21:06:55.020:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:645) 06-18 21:06:55.020:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4546)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:3813)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-18 21:06:55.020:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-18 21:06:55.020:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   06-18 21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 06-18
>   21:06:55.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: please put some code.

Comment: i have already mentioned code information in above question.

Answer (score 7):

Ok so after 2 days, I was able to solve a similar issue like this.

First do not persist your `ViewPager` in the `getView()`. What I mean by this is that you shouldn't call `convertView.setTag(holder);` or `holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag()`. Just remove the if statement that checks if `convertView` is null. Then completely remove the else statement block.

Another change to make (this is not one of the causes) is you need to optimize the way you set the Ids.
Instead of `setId(position+1)`, make an Ids.xml file in your values folder, then inside that file, put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
  <!-- use to generate non-conflicting ids for the viewpager -->

  <item name="viewpager_id_base" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Then in your `getView()` method replace `setId(position+1)` with `setId(R.id.viewpager_id_base + position)`

After the above change, the list will not crash, but it will disappear after you scroll the item off screen. Here is the fix for that:

Make sure your Custom `PageAdapter` extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, not `FragmentPagerAdapter`. This will properly destroy the views and trigger the onCreateView().

Comment: It's not my question.

Comment: oops, my bad. Welcome to stackoverflow anyways!

Comment: Hi Jessicardo your answer solved my issue.But it is giving me classcast exception can you suggest me where am I missing?

Comment: You mention using the resource to set the id, "generating non conflicting ids for the viewpager".  Wouldn't adding the "position" variable to that non-conflicting id cause a potential conflict for some other view that isn't a view pager?

Comment: I don't think so since the generated id is the last id. Unless you use the resource more than 1 place, then you need to implement your own logic.

Comment: with this approach, all cells in the memory will 
this is a very bad decision

Comment: @Jessicardo its only the last id given the name (they're sorted alphabetically), if you'd named it pager_id_base it'd probably appear in the middle of the list, and therefore adding + position to that value would clash with other ids as bboybz mentioned. I found that I had to create individual ids for as many rows as I wanted to support in my ListView and access them programatically to pass to setId().