# View Pager as List View Row Item

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a list view with 20 rows and I want to setup a view pager as each row in a list view. As the items coming in my row of the list view may one or more than one, and I want to show the list view row items using a view pager.

For this I am using the following code:

**Custom Layout which is to be shown in the list view row (as the pager item)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example Value"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
```

**Main List View Custom Row Item having View Pager**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mypager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyPagerAdapter Class**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_layout_file, null);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, position);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == ((View) obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

**List View Adapter GET VIEW METHOD**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list_item, null,false);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(context);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mypager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    return convertView;
}
```

I am getting no error and the view which is rendered after running it is always empty.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. can you please tell if you fix it?

Comment: Yes I can help you, Show me your code where you are getting the same. I would suggest to post a question with ur code and I will review it and answer you.

Comment: please here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774098/viewpager-within-listview-row-item

Comment: any luck in my question?!.. hope you can help me out, or at least solve your question and mark it as right, so we can relate to it. sorry for disturbing you and thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue and resolved it by providing id to the viewpager dynamically in the `getView()` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list_item, null,false);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(context);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mypager);

    **myPager.setId(position + getCount());**

    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    return convertView;
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was stuck for a month on this and the solution was so simple and so stupid.. I still don't understand

Comment: I'm getting an exception "Unable to find resource ID" when trying to use this method with a viewholder

Comment: This works. But when I scroll down and scroll back up, the viewpager is black. (it occupies the space physically, but other than that its blank)

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem.
Just give height to both viewpager and if needed your List View Row layout's main container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mypager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Height must be set by fix value. If you want to make it dynamic you can try from setting it in your coding at run time.

Answer (score 2):

I created sample app

**Example ViewPager with fragment**: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20178650/builds/listviewwithviewpager.zip

**BUT** there is one big drawback. All the cells are stored in memory, and the application can crash by low memory, whether you have a lot of cells

**EDIT:**

Empirically it has been found. If use simply view instead fragment in **ViewPager**.
I can write an adapter correctly and not be struck with the memory

**Example ViewPager with view:** 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20178650/builds/listviewwithviewpager_v2.zip

I hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in instantiateItem() from:

```
((ViewPager) container).addView(view, position);
```

to:

```
((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
        CustomeListModel customeListModel = arrayList.get(position);
        Utils.d("debug", "in get view method ");

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(context, customeListModel);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.viewPager= (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mypager);
        viewHolder.viewPager.setId(position + getCount());
        viewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewHolder.viewPager.setMinimumWidth(100);
    viewHolder.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    viewHolder.viewPager.setPageMargin(-380);

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: context captured from the constructor