# How to add ViewPager that contain images into listview?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, android-viewpager

Good day Developers, I already implement listview using base adapter, and now I want to add a view pager into listview row item, currently at row item 2. But I'm facing error. I think, it's about MeasureSpec on the listview.

This is ListView adapter using BaseAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView txt_urutan;
        TextView txt_menu;
        TextView txt_price;
        ImageView img_menu;
        ImageView img_arrow;

        if(v==null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_makanan, parent, false);
        }
        img_menu = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.picture_menu_on_listview);
        txt_urutan = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.urutan_makanan_ayam_listview);
        txt_menu = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nama_makanan_ayam_listview);
        txt_price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.harga_makanan_ayam_listview);
        img_arrow = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.arrow_on_listview);

        txt_urutan.setText(urutan_makanan_sambal[pos]);
        txt_menu.setText(jenis_menu_sambal[pos]);
        txt_price.setText(price_menu_sambal[pos]);
        img_menu.setImageResource(pic_menu.getResourceId(pos, -1));
        img_arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.nav_icon);

        return v;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This is horizontalscrollview.java:

```
public class HorizontalScrollViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ImageView img;
        if(v==null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_scroll_view, parent, false);
        }
        img =  (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
        return v;
    }
}
```

this is siteContentView class:

```
public class SiteContentPreview{
    public View getView(Context context, View v, SiteContentData siteContent){
        View result = v;
        if(result!=null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_image, null);
        }
        TextView siteNumber = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.custom_image_view_text);
        ImageView siteImage = (ImageView)result.findViewById(R.id.custom_image_view);
        if(siteContent != null){
            siteNumber.setText(siteContent.getSiteNumber());
            siteImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(siteContent.getSiteContentFrame()));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is siteContentData class:

```
public class SiteContentData{
    String holdString;
    String holdImagePath;

    public getSiteNumber(){
        return holdString;
    }

    public getSiteContentFrame(){
        return holdImagePath;
    }
}
```

This is horizontal_scroll_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hori_place_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is scroll_view.xml (to hold images that to be placed inside horizontal scroll view):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sambal_bajak_laut"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sambal_bawang"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

any help or idea would be very appreciated. Environment: Eclipse, ADT, Genymotion.

Comment: is there anyone who can help?

Comment: See this link. Might be of some help
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920459/placing-viewpager-as-a-row-in-listview

Comment: **Always**, when posting a stacktrace, highlight the line where the exception is thrown(line `402` in your adapter's `getView()` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a workaround.

Instead of adding a ViewPager you simply add a View extended by BaseAdapter.

In there you add a View with HorizontallScroll. The Click Event you can trigger with the ID of the corresponding View.

With this example you see how Horizontall implement: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/

Please take notice that you must set your child width (in your Case the picture) to match_parent. Use a Layout (that have match_parent) and in this Layout you place your picture with wrap_content, for none stretching the picture.

**EDIT 1:**

First you create your HorizontalScrollView Layout like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hori_place_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you create a AdapterView for your Layout that you want to place in the LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your Code you dynamically create and add the AdapterView (like you have) to the Linearlayout from your HorizontalScrollView.

**EDIT 2**

```
public class HorizontalScrollViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ...
        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            ImageView img_menu;
            if(v==null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horiscvi, parent, false);
            }
            // at this you must add your CustomeViewLayout
            return v;
        }
    }
```

And the adapter for CustomeView

```
public class CustomeViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ImageView img_menu;
        if(v==null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_makanan, parent, false);
        }
        img_menu = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.picture_menu_on_listview);
        v.addView(img_menu);
        return v;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

OK, now in your AdapterView you have a section thats looking like the following:

```
ArrayList<SiteContentData> siteContentData = new ArrayList<SiteContentData>();
        siteContentData.add(new SiteContentData("one", "yourpicone"));
        siteContentData.add(new SiteContentData("two", "yourpictwo"));
        siteContentData.add(new SiteContentData("three", "yourpicthree"));
        siteContentData.add(new SiteContentData("four", "yourpicfour"));

        horizontalScrollView = ((HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1));
        sitePreview = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hori_linear));

        for (SiteContentData siteContData : siteContentData)
        {
            View convertView;
            LayoutInflater inflaterCustomeShow =
                    (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflaterCustomeShow.inflate(R.layout.customeimage, null);
            View sitePreviewView =
                    SiteContentPreview.getView(getApplicationContext(), convertView, siteContData);

            sitePreview.addView(sitePreviewView);
        }
```

In this you initialize your scrollview with the linearlayout inside of this. Specially you adding the CustomeView inside of the linearlayout. The SiteContentData is just a pojo thats hold two strings, the first is some sample text and the second is the path to the image in your project.

And the SiteContentPreview looks like this:

```
public class SiteContentPreview
{
    public static View getView(Context context, View convertView, SiteContentData siteContent)
    {
        View result = convertView;
        if (result == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customeimage, null);
        }

        TextView siteNumber = ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.custome_imageview_text));
        ImageButton siteImage = ((ImageButton) result.findViewById(R.id.custome_image_view));
        if (siteContent != null)
        {
            siteNumber.setText(siteContent.getSiteNumber());
            siteImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(siteContent.getSiteContentFrame()));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

just simple assigning.

That's all.

The HorizontalScrollView Layout you are right and here is the Layout for the CustomeViewImage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custome_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custome_imageview_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That's all. enjoy. Hope you achieve what you want.

```
public class SiteContentData
{
private String siteNumber;
private String siteContentFrame;

public SiteContentData(String siteNumber, String siteContentFrame)
{
this.siteNumber = siteNumber;
this.siteContentFrame = siteContentFrame;
}

public String getSiteNumber()
{
return siteNumber;
}

public String getSiteContentFrame()
{
return siteContentFrame;
}

}
```

Comment: i try to implement horizontal scroll view, but i'm still confuse about how to inflate layout that fill horizontal scroll view, with my layout that contain listview extend base adapter. can you give me a sample how to achieve above view using horizontal scroll view?

Comment: Please see my Edit Answer. Feel free to ask more.

Comment: i already create 2 xml for horizontal scroll view layout & layout that contain image view. now should i inflate those 2 xml inside my ListviewAdapter? or should i create another class that extends AdapterView?

Comment: i can not inflate those 2 xml with my ListViewAdapter. because ListviewAdapter use another layout. i try to create a sub class called viewimagepage that extends AdapterView, but confuse how to implementing that adapter, can you help me ?

Comment: ok, your the hierarchy is the following: ListView -> Horizontal -> CustomeImageView. Take Notice, you create your CustomeImageView, then you inflate your HorizontalScrollView and add the CustomeImageView to your HorizontalScrollView, after this, you add the inflated HorizontalSV to your ListAdapter. Or have you other problems? And you right, you need for the HorizontalSV an Adapter and for your CustomeView an Adapter too.

Comment: sorry for asking this, but i still don't understand how to implement it. i still confuse about HorizontalSV should use which adapter?? and CustomImageView should use what adapter?

Comment: no problem. i try to give you a good as possible overview for my solution, but the problem now, i haven't a workingstation for this (at the time). Later I'm at home i can give you more details. But try it with this what i have posted for you. In the code, you have been created your ListViewLayout you need to instantiat a adapter for your custome row, in this case you start your Adapter class and in this adapterclass you instantiat the other adapter, like in my edit the horizontaladapter

Comment: I want to ask about `img_menu = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.picture_menu_on_listview);` on CustomeViewAdapter, should i add new image view inside `R.layout.list_makanan` ? or should i change it to `img_menu = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` ?

Comment: add a new image, like your first impression

Comment: sir, please look at my edited answer above. i already add modified source code that i have been working on. but it's still error. i don't know where should i put the HorizontalScrollViewAdapter.

Comment: where should i call class HorizontalScrollViewAdapter?? is it on ListViewAdapter at getView method?

Comment: yes, of course. remember my hierarchy suggestion: ListView -> Horizontal -> CustomeImageView. Have you tested it?

Comment: sir, i'm very sorry for interupting. i know this is my bad. i try to implement your code, but still facing error. what i want to ask is, could you look at my above code. i already edit it. right now i have a listviewadapter extends base adapter, and then i also create horizontalscrollview extends baseadapter. to be honest, i don't now how to call the horizontalscrollview adapter inside listview adapter. can you show me the way? thank you for time

Comment: so right now, my hierarchy is this: `Listview` -> `Horizontal`. in my above code, i haven't add CustomeViewAdapter. i haven't add it, because i don't now what layout should i use. can you assist? thanks

Comment: you must use the layout with the imageview inside. later i will try it out and send you an respone

Comment: sir, i already accept your answer, but to be honest, i still facing little issue. please look at my code above. i already add SiteContentPreview class and also CustomeViewImage.xml, what i want to ask is, can you show me the code inside `getSiteNumber()` and `getSiteContentFrame()`??

Comment: these two methods not magic, there ary simple getter methods there return an string. take a look at my updated answer

Comment: sir, i already edit again my code above, so i put `return holdString;` and `return holdImagePath;` in SiteContentData() method, is it true??? and i want to ask about `siteContentData.add(new SiteContentData("one", "yourpicone"));`, what i want to ask is, what should i replace with on `yourpicone`? is it image path from my computer??? similar like `D:\project\App\res\drawable\fanta.jpg` ?? thanks.