# MediaPlayer inside ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using the below code for viewpage inside listview.

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) currentView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setId(position + 1);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(30);
    ViewPagerAdapter tempMyFriendPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager, mItems.get(position).getViewPagerItems());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tempMyFriendPagerAdapter);
```

Code taken from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20178650/builds/listviewwithviewpager.zip

Now say I scroll the listview fast to the bottom, the listview items at top gets destroyed however the first fragment of viewpager is still in memory causing it to show partially on screen.
[image: scroll issue]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Implement view holder pattern for your listview

Comment: I recommend using the example of the view