# Image slider using View Pager issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an activity which contains a **listView**. Each item of the listView contains a swipeable set of images (which I have unsuccessfully tried to implement using a **ViewPager**).

My issue is this: when I try to implement a simple image slider using a view pager (i.e. Activity contains a ViewPager, and the View Pager's adapter supplies the images), the output is as expected, but if I try doing what I have mentioned in the previous paragraph (i.e. The Activity contains a listView and each item of the listView is a ViewPager which displays a swipeable set of images), I get a blank output. Please help me out! I have posted some code below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stylistDisplay);

    //To keep things simple I am sending only one item of the list to the adapter

    list.setAdapter(new StylistAdapter(Cart.getList().get(0), this));
}

static class StylistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Stylist stylistObj;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public StylistAdapter(Stylist obj, Context context) {
        this.stylistObj = obj;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = ((Activity)this.context).getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return stylistObj;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewItem item;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stylist_photos_view_pager, null);
            item = new ViewItem();
            item.photosViewPager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photos_view_pager);
            convertView.setTag(item);
        } else {
            item = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        PhotosAdapter adapter = new PhotosAdapter(context);
        item.photosViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewItem {
        ViewPager photosViewPager;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
  <FrameLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.temp.customer.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/stylistDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="@color/backGround"
    android:padding="13.3dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**stylist_photos_view_pager**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/photos_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PhotosAdapter.java**

```
public class PhotosAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
};
public PhotosAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stylist_individual_details, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    textView1.setText("hello world");
    ((ViewPager)container).addView(viewItem);

    return viewItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    boolean temp = view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    return temp;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar issue, and have to say that it is a bad idea to use ViewPager as a listItem, since ViewPager is supposed to be used for fragments primarily.

I guess that your functionality should be similar to some horizontal pictures, on the main feed which is vertical. You can think of using horizontal scroll views which is a bit of a pain, but still more realistic to do that. You might also end up managing your own scrolling behavior, which might already be implemented by some libraries.

BUT I MIGHT BE WRONG!
This thread has a similar issue:

[Placing ViewPager as a row in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920459/placing-viewpager-as-a-row-in-listview)

Comment: How did you fix the issue when you faced it?

Answer (score 0):

After reading around for a while I tried explicitly setting the height of the viewPager and its parent. This worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dip" >
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I don't know if there is a better solution, but if you do get a better solution please comment!